# How to see the exception message when 'Pause on Exceptions' is turned on in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, exception

When I turn on **Pause on Exceptions** in Chrome, it correctly pauses when a JavaScript error pops up, but I don't see the exception message itself.

Is there any way to see the message *before* having to click continue?

**Note** sometimes it is possible to try to read it from the source code, but this is far from ideal, because it might include multiple variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the exception object in the **Scope** → **Local** section:

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot. Still don't get why they don't reserve a bit more screen estate for this. Quite an essential part of debugging in my opinion.

Comment: @DirkBoer guess google is too poor to afford to pay someone to implement a tooltip. it being bleeding edge technology and all :(